# Creating Multifield Indexes in Mongoose / MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find documentation, to no avail, on how to create multi-field indexes in Mongoosejs. In particular I have two fields that need to be indexed and unique. What is an example mongoose schema that indexes two fields together?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

You call the `index` method on your `Schema` object to do that as shown [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes).  For your case it would be something like:

```
mySchema.index({field1: 1, field2: 1}, {unique: true});
```

Comment: This is called the Compount Index in mongodb. So it creates indexes as field1 and field1 + field2. So it is first index according to field1 and then inside field1 with respect to field 2

Comment: what is the meaning of the 1 after field1: and field2:  ?

Comment: @DamonYuan They set the sort order of the fields in the index. `1` is ascending, `-1` would be descending.

Comment: @KetanGhumatkar
 How are you sure that it is field1 and field1 + field2, and not viceversa i.e. field2 and field2 + field1?

Comment: @KetanGhumatkar It's based on the order the fields are listed in the object in the call to `index`.

Comment: `1` and `-1`  specifies a ascending  or a descending index key on the index field.
I found docs [http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/tutorials/create-indexes/](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/tutorials/create-indexes)

Comment: i do not think the `unique` works with compound indexes.

Comment: creating Index option using code works in case you have 'autoIndex' set to true, however this is not an good practice in production as it put significant load. 
 https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes

Answer (score 13):

Defining indexes at the schema level is necessary when creating compound indexes.

```
animalSchema.index({ name: 1, type: -1 });
```

Reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes

Comment: What is the meaning of 1 and -1? I couldn't find this in the documentation that you referenced to. Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer on this page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/ Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This should help ;)

```
import { Schema, Document, model } from 'mongoose';

import { IUser } from './User';
import { IMood } from './Mood';
import { ILocation } from './Location';

export interface IUserMoodLocation extends Document {
    userId?: IUser['_id'];
    moodId?: IMood['_id'];
    locationId?: ILocation['_id'];
}

const UserMoodLocationSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    moodId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Mood'
    },
    locationId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Location'
    }
});

UserMoodLocationSchema.index(
    { userId: 1, moodId: 1, locationId: 1 },
    { unique: true }
);

export const UserMoodLocation = model<IUserMoodLocation>(
    'UserMoodLocation',
    UserMoodLocationSchema
);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
    Following command can be used to create compound index for nested json:
    db.ACCOUNT_collection.createIndex({"account.id":1,"account.customerId":1},{unique:1}) 
Mongo json structure is like :
{"_id":"648738"
 "account": { 
    "id": "123",
    "customerId": 7879,
    "name": "test"
   ..
   ..

  }
}
```

I have tested with sample data it is perfectly working as expected.

Comment: We don't want that with mongooses shell we want that with node js schema

Answer (score -5):

By the way, the accepted answer is wrong, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553550/129300 you should wrap the field names in single quotes, ie:

```
mySchema.index({'field1': 1, 'field2': 1}, {unique: true});
```

Happy Day!

Comment: Object keys in JS can be unquoted as long as they're syntactically-valid identifiers. `field1` and `field2` are valid identifiers. `field1.foo` isn't, for example.

Comment: The answer is working though, but the accepted answer isn't wrong either as far as the object keys are valid.