# How to create MongoDB indexes in NodeJS app using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

According to [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) , the index should not be defined on the schema and should be disabled in production. I am confused as to what is being recommended. If index should not be defined in the mongoose schema then how it should be created in NodeJS app?

Comment: Nothing wrong with defining the index in the schema. See here for a related question about what's likely confusing you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342708/mongoose-indexing-in-production-code

Comment: As @JohnnyHK mentioned, the link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342708/mongoose-indexing-in-production-code) clarified the confusion.