# Creating Multifield(more than 2) Indexes in Mongoose / MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I see solution here:
[Creating Multifield Indexes in Mongoose / MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573753/creating-multifield-indexes-in-mongoose-mongodb?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

How about 3、4、5... fields?

Here is my coffeescript code:

```
selectRecordSchema = new Schema
  srcSysId: { type: String, required: true }
  desSysId: { type: String, required: true }
  stuId: { type: String, required: true }
  courseId: { type: String, required: true }

selectRecordSchema.index { srcSysId: 1, desSysId: 1,stuId: 1,courseId: 1 }, { unique: true}
```

And this works:

```
selectRecordSchema.index { srcSysId: 1, desSysId: 1}, { unique: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit for field count ( while you are not hitting something like memory limit, max doc size is 16MB )

```
mySchema.index({field1: 1, field2: 1, field3: 1, field4: 1, field5: 1, field6: 1}, {unique: true});
```

Comment: I trid,but this failed.I can create 2 same records

Comment: In mongoose, you if you modify schema, you must drop the collection to make the new schema work. Did you do that?