# Combination of multiple column unique mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

***Objective***

*To create uniqueness for two columns*

***what i tried***

Here is my schema,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// location table Schema

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    locationId: { type: String, required: true },
    stockingLocationId: { type: String, required: true},
    parentStockingLocationId: { type: String },
    stockingLocationDescription: { type: String },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now  },
    lastModified: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    isActive: { type: Boolean , default : true },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean , default : false }

});
```

Two columns are `locationId` and `stockingLocationId`.

I tried `locationSchema.index({locationId:1, stockingLocationId:1}, { unique: true });`

but not works,

Any help Please?

Comment: Can you please tell me why negative ?

Comment: @ramamoorthy-villi The code is correct. Once drop the database and restart the server. Then check whether it is working!

Comment: @Vishnu, thanks that is working after i adding   index:true  like     locationId: { type: String, required: true,index:true },
    stockingLocationId: { type: String, required: true,index:true} in the schema

Answer (score 11):

It worked for me, after adding single quotes around the fields like below

```
mySchema.index({'field1': 1, 'field2': 1}, {unique: true});
```

Comment: Worked for me after adding quotes to field name. Cheers!

Comment: TWO THINGS: this should be the OFFICIAL ANSWER, and also, mongoose developers should be fired.

Comment: @FerMartin This has nothing to do with Mongoose devs; this is how all [all objects work in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes).

Comment: @Mike I believe 'filed1' is a valid identifier in javascript, therefore following your link, there should not be any difference, correct?

Comment: @FerMartin That is correct. As long as your object property names are valid identifier names, you don't need to put quotes around them.

Answer (score 9):

I know it's a little late but something along these lines..

```
mySchema.index({field1: 1, field2: 1}, {unique: true});
```

as specified in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573753/creating-multifield-indexes-in-mongoose-mongodb)

Answer (score 5):

You need to drop your db after you change your index schema

Comment: I downvoted but later realised it's actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make separate calls for the two columns. The way you do it, the combination of the two columns will be unique (combined unique key).

```
locationSchema.index({locationId:1}, { unique: true });
locationSchema.index({stockingLocationId:1}, { unique: true });
```

Comment: I want combination of those two fields

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as following in your schema itself:

```
 locationId: { type: String, required: true, unique:true, index:true },
 stockingLocationId: { type: String, required: true, unique:true, index:true},
```