# Create a composite case-insensitive unique key/index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, case-insensitive, composite-key

I have a collection test1 with this schema :

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("576a5306177a78b5c286c95d"),
 "name" : "abdul",
 "lname" : "sayed"
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("576a5306177a78b5c286c95d"),
 "name" : "abcd",
 "lname" : "port"
}
```

I want to create a **unique case-insensitive index** on this collection for columns name & lname :

For the current eg :

1) "Abdul" & "Sayed" cannnot be added. (which is correct)

2) "Abdul" & "pqrs" should get added. 
However I am unable to add so.

It is giving me this error.

> db.test1.insert({"name":"Abdul","lname":"pqrs"})
>
> WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>
> > db.test1.insert({"name":"Abdul","lname":"pqrs"}) WriteResult({
> >             "nInserted" : 0,
> >             "writeError" : {
> >                     "code" : 11000,
> >                     "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: mydb.test1 index: name_text_lname_text dup key: { : \"abdul\", : 1.1
> >     }"
> >             } })

**What I Had tried :**

```
db.test1.createIndex({"name":"text","lname":"text"},{unique:true,"caseInsensitive":true})
```

**Edit :** List of Indexes :

```
> db.test1.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "mydb.test1"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                },
                "name" : "name_text_lname_text",
                "ns" : "mydb.test1",
                "caseInsensitive" : true,
                "weights" : {
                        "lname" : 1,
                        "name" : 1
                },
                "default_language" : "english",
                "language_override" : "language",
                "textIndexVersion" : 3
        }
]
>
```

Comment: Can [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573753/creating-multifield-indexes-in-mongoose-mongodb) help you understanding your problem?

Comment: Console output pasted here shows, record with  `db.test1.insert({"name":"Abdul","lname":"pqrs"})

WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })` is inserted and for the next time it is saying duplicate, which is correct. What is the issue you are facing

Comment: can you show a list of indexes on the collection?

Comment: @Tiramisu please check the edit

Comment: @ClementAmarnath It did not insert the record at all. Even I had got confused with the result

Comment: @Shrabanee : My index needs to be case insensitive & unique.

Comment: You got that error because you were duplicating: _fts, and _ftsx--the keys in your index by leaving them blank.

try adding: 
db.test1.createIndex({"name":1, "lname":1}, {unique: true});

also drop your text index and recreate it without enforcing uniqueness.

Comment: @Tiramisu but that wont create a case insensitive unique index for me..I need a unique index which is case insensitive.

Comment: Hi @AbdulRehmanSayed, I ran into this one again and to make an index case insensitive you need to specify a collation in the index. Specify that collation when you create the collection and when you query it.