# mongoose - avoid duplicate when all fields are equal to new entry

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

so I have a mongoose schema in my node application with two fields: **tag** and **task**, and I want to be able to save entries where the combination of both properties doesnt exist yet.

For example: my DB already has the following entries:

- {tag:**tag1**, task:**task1**}
- {tag:**tag1**, task:**task2**}
- {tag:**tag2**, task:**task1**}

I want to be able to create {tag:**tag2**, task:**task2**}, but not {tag:**tag1**, task:**task1**} again, so I guess I cant use primary or unique in any of those fields, since they can repeat, except when their combination already exists

so which query should I use to save? Or should I find if it already exists first?

Comment: You should go with compound indexing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573753/creating-multifield-indexes-in-mongoose-mongodb

Comment: You can `update(obj, obj)` with `upsert: true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Unique Compound Indexing

```
db.users.createIndex( { "tag": 1, "task": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

For more info visit the [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/)